# When someone sticks adhesive tape on surveillance cameras so that they don't capture anything, what verb do you use to describe the action?

Tags: word-request, verbs

Tape them? Plaster them? Stick them over? Is there any one-word way (or a phrasal verb) to describe it? Dictionaries didn't help me

Comment: I don't know of any specific phrase or word but **disable** and **deactivate** would serve. You could also talk about **blinding the cameras** or **putting them out of action**.

Comment: Maybe **vandalise**, particularly if it were done for no other reason than to annoy the owners of the camera.

Comment: **Tag** could also work, given context.

Comment: I hear the term "**covering** laptop cameras" or "**taping** laptop cameras **shut**" quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either:

Something about loss of vision: "blocking", "blinding", "covering"

or something tape-related: "masking" perhaps.

Other methods might have their own specific verbs "to spray-paint", "to bag" for example.

Comment: Blinding works best. Also obscuring.

Comment: I liked "blinding". I didn't include "obscuring" because you have to "obscure the camera's view" since just "obscuring the camera" might mean my view of the camera was obscured rather than the other way around.